# How to start Windows 7 application "recent session" programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7

Here I'm NOT referring to just starting a Windows application. What I want is to utilize Windows functionality of "Recent sessions" which can be visible for example here: [image: A screenshot of Windows taskbar]

I'd like to know how to start those recent sessions programmatically when I know the name of the session.

So far my own searches only leaded to loads of articles on starting the applications - but no description of specifically "Recent sessions" mechanism.

UPDATE:

Seems I was not clear enough. I know that from my C# application (WinForms) I can start external processes using something like:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
Process process = new Process();
// Configure the process using the StartInfo properties.
process.StartInfo.FileName = "process.exe";
process.Start();
```

My question actually is: Is there any way - by specifying any options of `process.StartInfo` OR by using any other possible way to start external process - to start not just an external application, but a "Recent session" of this external application if I have this "Recent session" name already.

Comment: I think you should edit your question and focus on asking the question "*How do I programmaticly view the content of the extended right click menu some programs provide in the start menu*" As you say, you already know how to start the program if you new the correct command line arguments, you just need to figure out where that data in the right click menu is stored (all those items do in that list is launch the program with a special set of command line args).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is supposed to be by design, but it is definitely different behavior than earlier versions, and it is very annoying (at least for me).

First off, I don't use the tabbed session feature often. I much prefer a separate window per session (selectable via Win7 task bar).

In versions pre-5.2, opening a pinned or recent session from the jump list will prompt for password and open the session in a new window.

In 5.2 beta, opening a pinned or recent session from the jump list will prompt for password and open the session in an existing WinSCP window. What is even more annoying, however, is that focus does not switch to the window, so if you have an existing WinSCP window behind other windows it will be prompting for a password without any visible indication that user intervention is required (i.e. you have to click to show the existing WinSCP window and then you will see a prompt waiting).

What would be really nice is preference options for: 
 1) Disabling tabbed sessions entirely 
 2) Opening new sessions from jump list in new windows

At the very least a reused window needs to be given focus (even for a password prompt), but I also would hope that WinSCP will still cater to those who prefer separate windows. Thanks.

Comment: I was probably not specific enough and did not put an emphasis on the word "programmatically". Updated my question so it's more precise.